# Seat Reserving system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

the Image shows how my tables are setup

[image]

**Update**

I have a working reserve seat and add to booking table now.

```
//
    // POST: /Home/CreateBooking

    public ActionResult CreateBooking(String id, DateTime date, DateTime time)
    {
        ViewData["username"] = User.Identity.Name;
        ViewData["performanceDate"] = date;
        ViewData["Venue"] = id;

        BookingCreate model = new BookingCreate();
        model.Seats = (from c in _db.Seat
                       where c.venue == id
                       select c);



        return this.View(model);

    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult CreateBooking(BookingCreate bookingCreate, IList<String> seatNumber)
    {

        Customer theCustomer
            = (from c in _db.Customer
               select c).First<Customer>(c => c.username == bookingCreate.customer);


        //performance details for the performance selected by the user
        Performance thePerformance
            = (from p in _db.Performance
               select p).FirstOrDefault<Performance>(p => p.performanceDate == bookingCreate.performanceDate || p.performanceTime == bookingCreate.performanceTime || p.venue == bookingCreate.venue);

        //performance details for the performance selected by the user
        Performance seatbooking
            = (from p in _db.Performance
               select p).FirstOrDefault<Performance>(p => p.performanceDate == bookingCreate.performanceDate || p.performanceTime == bookingCreate.performanceTime || p.venue == bookingCreate.venue);


        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var bookingToCreate = new Booking();
        bookingToCreate.bookingDate = now;
        bookingToCreate.bookingTime = now;
        bookingToCreate.bookingType = "Web";
        bookingToCreate.collect = true;
        bookingToCreate.Customer = theCustomer;
        bookingToCreate.Performance = thePerformance;




        _db.AddToBooking(bookingToCreate);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        var bookingnumber = (from p in _db.Booking
                             select p.bookingNo);



        foreach (var displaySeat in seatNumber)
        {


            Seat theseat
      = (from c in _db.Seat

         select c).FirstOrDefault<Seat>(c => c.seatNumber == displaySeat);


            var seatBooking = new SeatBooking();

            seatBooking.Booking = bookingToCreate;
            seatBooking.Seat = theseat;




            _db.AddToSeatBooking(seatBooking);
            _db.SaveChanges();

        }

        return RedirectToAction("ShowsIndex");
    }
```

The code ensures that the correct venue's seats are displayed and that the logged in user and selected performance is chosen.

What i am stuck with is..

I am currently outputting the seats as checkboxes

with

```
BookingCreate model = new BookingCreate();
                model.Seats = (from c in _db.Seat
                               where c.venue == id
                           select c);
```

But I would like for the checkboxes to show what seat number they relate to (at the moment they are just a blank checkbox)

And also how to stop showing seats that have been booked to stop duplication.

Thanks

Comment: What are you looking for?? an advise of how to do it or how should it look like?

Comment: So basically you want someone to do your high level design for you?  I suggest you spend some time doing this yourself, and come back to SO if you have any specific problems.

Comment: @sajoshi Was just after some advice on if what i was thinking was a good method of doing it. And if any1 knew of any online tutorials etc.

Comment: @sajoshi @ UpTheCreek I have updated the question with what i have done.

Comment: First you need to define the requirements from your system and thoroughly design the user interface. Then you can start thinking about the structure of tables and business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way  (providing there are surrogate primary keys Customer.Id and Performance.Id)

```
public class BookingToCreateVM
{
    public int BookingNo{get; set;}
    //..etc - all necessary booking fields

    public Guid UserId{get; set;}
    public Guid PerformanceId{get; set;}

    //data for something like dropdowns in view
    public IList<Customer> Users{get; set;}
    public IList<Performance> Performances{get; set;}
}
```

and the controller action

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CreateBooking(BookingToCreateVM bookingToCreateVM)
{

    Customer theCustomer
        = (from c in _db.Customer
           select c).Single<Customer>(c=>c.Id == bookingToCreateVM.UserId);


    Performance thePerformance
        = (from p in _db.Performance
           select p).Single<Performance>(p=> p.Id == bookingToCreateVM.PerformanceId);

    var bookingToCreate = new Booking();  
    bookingToCreate.BookingNo= bookingToCreateVM.BookingNo;
    //..etc - initialize all necessary fields
    bookingToCreate.Customer = theCustomer;
    bookingToCreate.Performance = thePerformance;

    _db.AddToBooking(bookingToCreate);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ListBookings");
}
```